# Click and drag draw electronics components in java swing

Tags: java, swing, line

I'm trying to design a OrCad of sorts in Java and so far I decided to use lines with different colours to represent each component. I tested my code by drawing lines and it worked (click and dragged and then repainted when drawing a new line) but I don't know why it's not working anymore now that I'm trying to draw my components instead of simple Line2D.

I have a class components and a few basic derived components and each have a Line2D field and a colour field.
The drawing is done with a popup menu (user right clicks to choose the component) and then when they start clicking and dragging a component object is created and added to an array that's always redrawn.

This is the main class:

```
public class Main {
private static String checked;


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    createAndShowGUI();
}

private static void createAndShowGUI()
{
    DrawingArea drawingArea = new DrawingArea();
    PopUpMenu popup = new PopUpMenu();
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.getContentPane().add(drawingArea);
    frame.getContentPane().add(popup);
    frame.setSize(900, 500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

static class PopUpMenu extends JPanel {

    public PopUpMenu()
    {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        JPopupMenu pmenu = new JPopupMenu();
        JMenuItem resistance = new JMenuItem("Add Resitance");
        JMenuItem wire = new JMenuItem("Add Wire");
        JMenuItem capacitor = new JMenuItem("Add Capacitor");
        JMenuItem source = new JMenuItem("Add Source");

        pmenu.add(resistance);
        pmenu.add(wire);
        pmenu.add(capacitor);
        pmenu.add(source);

        resistance.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                checked = "R";

            }

        });

        wire.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                checked = "W";

            }

        });

        capacitor.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                checked = "C";

            }

        });

        source.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                checked = "S";

            }

        });

        addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
              public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                  if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
                  {
                      pmenu.show(e.getComponent(),e.getX(),e.getY());
                  }
               }

        });

    }
```

}

```
static class DrawingArea extends JPanel
{

    private ArrayList<Component> lines = new ArrayList<Component>();
    private Component shape;

    public DrawingArea()
    {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        MyMouseListener ml = new MyMouseListener();
        addMouseListener(ml);
        addMouseMotionListener(ml);
    }


protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);


    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    //g2d.setColor( Color.RED );
     g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3,  BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL));


    for (Component aux : lines)
    {
        g2d.setColor(aux.getCul());
        g2d.drawLine((int)aux.getLine().getX1(), (int)aux.getLine().getY1(), (int)aux.getLine().getX2(), (int)aux.getLine().getY2());
    }


    if (shape != null)
    {
        g2d.draw( shape.getLine() );
    }
}


class MyMouseListener extends MouseInputAdapter
{
    private Point startPoint;
    private Point endPoint;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        startPoint = e.getPoint();
        switch(checked)
        {
        case "W": shape = new Wire();
                break;
        case "R": shape = new Resistance();
                break;
        case "C": shape = new Capacitor();
                break;
        case "S": shape = new Source();
                break;
        }
        lines.add(shape);
    }
    public Line2D el = null;

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        endPoint = e.getPoint();

        el.setLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
        shape.setLine(el);
        repaint();
    }

     public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
       endPoint = e.getPoint();
       el.setLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
        shape.setLine(el);
       repaint();
        }
}
}
```

}

And these are my components (I only added one derived class).

```
public class Component {
protected double value;
protected Line2D line;
protected int ID;
protected Color cul;
protected String type;

public Component()
{

}


public String getType() {
    return type;
}



public Line2D getLine() {
    return line;
}

public void setLine(Line2D line) {
    this.line = line;
}

public int getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(int iD) {
    ID = iD;
}

public Color getCul() {
    return cul;
}

public int returnX1() {
    return (int)line.getP1().getX();
}

public int returnY1() {
    return (int)line.getP1().getY();
}

public int returnX2() {
    return (int)line.getP2().getX();
}

public int returnY2() {
    return (int)line.getP2().getY();
}
```

}

public class Capacitor extends Component {

```
private double value;
private Line2D line;
private int ID;
private Color cul = Color.ORANGE;
private String type = "C";

public Capacitor(){
    super();
}

@Override
public String getType() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return type;
}

@Override
public Line2D getLine() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getLine();
}
@Override
public void setLine(Line2D line) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.setLine(line);
}
@Override
public int getID() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getID();
}
@Override
public void setID(int iD) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.setID(iD);
}
@Override
public Color getCul() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return cul;
}
@Override
public int returnX1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.returnX1();
}
@Override
public int returnY1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.returnY1();
}
@Override
public int returnX2() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.returnX2();
}
@Override
public int returnY2() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.returnY2();
}
}
```

I feel it's got something to do with the way I copy the line in the mouse dragged and released methods.

Comment: Welcome to SO. `lines = new ArrayList<Component>();` I don't see you ever add Components to it. Also where is `Component` defined ?  When posting code I recommend creating [mcve]. I find it a very useful technique. Not only it makes helping much easier, it 
is a powerful debugging tool. It many case, while preparing one, you are likely to find the problem.

Comment: Thanks, didn't expect and answer so fast, I appreciate you taking the time to answer.  I add them when the user first clicks the mouse to drag and draw thenr: public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        startPoint = e.getPoint();
        switch(checked)
        {
        case "W": shape = new Wire();
                break;
        case "R": shape = new Resistance();
                break;
        case "C": shape = new Capacitor();
                break;
        case "S": shape = new Source();
                break;
        }
        lines.add(shape);
    }

Comment: [mcve] would have made helping much simpler and more efficient